# Protractor File Upload with Saucelabs

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, protractor, saucelabs

I'm testing an AngularJS project using protractor.  I have an image file upload tests which is working and passing correctly on my local mac machine.  However, when I run the same test via saucelabs the test fails.

Saucelabs is having problems finding the file and just opens a dialog box but can't find the file.  The file is within my test solution and not in saucelabs.  I've looked around on the web for answers but I haven't seen a definitive answer to resolve this particular problem.  Below is an example of the code I am using to upload an image file against an application.

```
var path = require('path');

it('should upload a file', function() {
  var fileToUpload = '../some/path/foo.txt',
  absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);

  $('input[type="file"]').sendKeys(absolutePath);    
  $('#uploadButton').click();
});
```

Any help or suggestions on how to get the above code to work via Saucelabs will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
browser.driver.setFileDetector(new browser.driver.remote.FileDetector);
```

According to [the protractor issue](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/612) it's either that or it's not working (bug in Selenium JavaScript bindings or protractor, or version mismatch).

In the same github issue there's also [a workaround](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/612#issuecomment-44686308) if the main solution didn't work (tldr: file sharing).

Comment: the FileDetector will translate the local file path to a temporary path on the SeleniumServer and perform them upload.  This is the correct way to do it.